# Mongoose select array item in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having an issue trying to select an array element by its id without having its parent id. So using the following as an example, I want to select a section with _id of 5 to save a change to it. Here is what that looks like:

```
site: {
  menus: [
    {
      _id: 1
      sections:[
        { _id: 1 },
        { _id: 2 },
        { _id: 3 },
        { _id: 4 }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: 2
      sections:[
        { _id: 5 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Schemas.Site.findOne({ _id: req.session.siteID, 'menus.sections._id': req.params.sectionID }).select('menus.$.sections').exec(function(err, site){
  if (err) return next(err);

  var section = site.menus[0].sections.id(req.params.sectionID);
  // update some things
  section.whatever = something;
  // save changes
  site.save();
});
```

The problem is that this works in the first menus array, but not in the second. If I try this on the second menu section (_id: 5), it updates in the first menu. I'm sure I have this close but probably a problem with the selecting. These are just arrays, not embedded models.

**Update:** It seems that the selection is working fine. When I console.log out the section variable, it has the proper item in the array. The problem happens when save is called. It overwrites the wrong item. I have no save middleware running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working by using the menuID and the sectionID now. I just updated it to look like this:

```
var menu = site.menus.id(req.body.menuID),
    section = menu.sections.id(req.params.sectionID);
```

I will leave this question unanswered for a bit in case there is a better way to do this without needing the menuID.